# What is the most accurate way to translate "ἐκ" in 1 Cor 11:28?

Tags: greek, word-study, grammar, translation-philosophy

I have made an effort to translate the following text.

> 1Cor 11:28 Δοκιμαζέτω(let - prove or examine) δὲ(but) ἄνθρωπος(a
>   man) ἑαυτόν(himself), καὶ(and) οὕτως(in-this-way) ἐκ(out) τοῦ(of
>   the) ἄρτου(bread) ἐσθιέτω(let him eat), καὶ(and) ἐκ(out) τοῦ(of
>   the) ποτηρίου(cup) πινέτω(drink).

My question is a matter of technical accuracy.  Most Lexicons have the most prevalent understanding of ἐκ is “out of” or “out from”.  But many translations seem to be translating ἐκ as simply “of”.  “Of’ doesn’t seem to convey the strength of “out of”.  When referring to the cup “out of” seems very appropriate, “and drink out of the cup”.

When the bread is concerned “let him eat out of the bread”, doesn’t seem to fit the idea of eating “the bread”.

Is the proper English phrasing simply, “let him eat of the bread and drink of the cup” and simply ignore the “out” idea?

Comment: Welcome to BH. A good question (+1).

Answer (score 3):

Daniel B Wallace in his book "Beyond the Basics" [1996, p371] lists six different shades of meaning for εκ+genitive :

- 1. Source : *out of, from*
- 2. Separation : *away from, from*
- 3. Temporal : *from, from* [this point] ... *on* [wards]
- 4. Cause : *because of*
- 5. Partitive (i.e. substituting for a partitive genitive) : *of*
- 6. Means : *by, from*

It is impossible for a lexicon to give simply one definition which encompasses the entire spectrum of meaning of a Greek preposition. Nor does the diagram in a Greek grammar (usually with a cube or sphere with arrows going in and out of it) fully demonstrate the flexibility of the powerful part of speech known as 'preposition' which enhances and extends (by considerable proportions) the active concepts expressed in verbs.

The diagram is good enough for a schoolboy to use to struggle through an exam but it is not nearly good enough in the sphere of Biblical Hermeneutics.

The above list indicates, and the variety of translations of single words indicates, that the power of prepositions cannot be encapsulated in a tight container of even two or three 'standard' renderings.

============================================================================

With regard to I Corinthians 11:28 :

> εκ του αρτου εσθιετω και εκ του ποτηριου πινετω
>
> (Received Text - Stephens, Beza, Elzevir and Scrivener all identical)

The following sources translate thusly :

> ... and so let him eat of that bread, and drink of that cup. [KJV]
>
> ... and so let him eat of the bread, and let him drink of the cup. [Green's Literal]
>
> ... and so of the bread let him eat, and of the cup let him drink. [Young's Literal]
>
> ... and so let hi eate of the breed and drynke of the cup. [Tyndale]
>
> ... and thus eat of the bread and drink of the cup. [J N Darby]

From the Latin Vulgate :

> ... and so ete he of `the ilke breed, and drynke of the cuppe. [Wycliffe]
>
> ... and so let him eat of the bread and drink of the chalice. [Douay-Rheims, Jerome/Challoner]

All of the above authorities, by using 'of', are expressing only the Partitive Genitive (see above in the Daniel B Wallace list) rather than the 'Source' meaning (see above again). That is to say the meaning is being taken as simply that of one thing being divided into parts and one part being focused upon which came from that division.

Your inclination to ignore any inclusion of an 'out of' idea (which conveys the meaning of a single thing coming out of a single source) seems to agree with the above authorities.

=========================================================================

I think you have highlighted the fact that the passage is focusing not on the *source* of the morsel of bread or the sip of wine, but is focusing on the *shared aspect* (a partitive concept) of the memorial ceremony.

Comment: Great answer - +1

Answer (score 0):

When you say "most lexicons" perhaps you could quote the main lexicon you consulted and we can all be on the same page. It sounds like perhaps what you were consulting was actually a concordance. A proper lexicon would give you much more complete and accurate information than that.

Below I've quoted BDAG, the premier Greek Bible lexicon. You will notice that it has a great deal of information other than just a gloss or two and it shows that it can be used as a marker of separation denoting "away from":

```
ἐκ, before vowels ἐξ, prep. w. gen. (Hom.+; s. lit. s.v. ἀνά and εἰς beg.)

**① marker denoting separation, from, out of, away from**

**ⓐ w. the place or thing fr. which separation takes place. Hence esp. w. verbs of motion** ἀναβαίνω, ἀναλύω, ἀνίστημι, ἐγείρομαι, εἰσέρχομαι, ἐκβάλλω, ἐκπορεύομαι, ἐξέρχομαι, ἔρχομαι, ἥκω, καταβαίνω, μεταβαίνω, ῥύομαι, συνάγω, φεύγω; s. these entries. καλεῖν ἐξ Αἰγύπτου Mt 2:15 (Hos 11:1); ἐκ σκότους 1 Pt 2:9. αἴρειν ἐκ τ. κόσμου J 17:15. ἐξαλείφειν ἐκ τῆς βίβλου Rv 3:5 (Ex 32:32f; Ps 68:29). ἀποκυλίειν τ. λίθον ἐκ τ. θύρας Mk 16:3; cp. J 20:1; Rv 6:14; σῴζειν ἐκ γῆς Αἰγ. Jd 5; διασῴζειν ἐκ τ. θαλάσσης Ac 28:4. παραγίνεσθαι ἐξ ὁδοῦ arrive on a journey (lit. from, i.e. interrupting a journey) Lk 11:6; fig. ἐπιστρέφειν ἐξ ὁδοῦ bring back fr. the way Js 5:20; cp. 2 Pt 2:21. ἐκ τῆς χειρός τινος (Hebraistically מִיַּד פּ׳, oft. LXX; s. B-D-F §217, 2; Rob. 649) from someone’s power ἐξέρχεσθαι J 10:39; ἁρπάζειν 10:28f (cp. Plut., Ages. 615 [34, 6] ἐκ τῶν χειρῶν τῶν Ἐπαμινώνδου τ. πόλιν ἐξαρπάσας; JosAs 12:8 ἅρπασόν με ἐκ χειρὸς τοῦ ἐχθροῦ); ἐξαιρεῖσθαι Ac 12:11 (cp. Aeschin. 3, 256 ἐκ τ. χειρῶν ἐξελέσθαι τῶν Φιλίππου; Sir 4:9; Bar 4:18, 21 al.); ῥύεσθαι Lk 1:74; cp. vs. 71 (Ps 105:10; Wsd 2:18; JosAs 12:10); εἰρυσταί σε κύριος ἐκ χειρὸς ἀνόμου AcPlCor 1:8 (cp. ἐκ τούτων ἄπαντων PsSol 13:4).—**After πίνειν, of the object fr. which one drinks** (X., Cyr. 5, 3, 3): ἐκ τ. ποτηρίου Mt 26:27; Mk 14:23; **1 Cor 11:28;** cp. 10:4; J 4:12. Sim. φαγεῖν ἐκ τ. θυσιαστηρίου Hb 13:10.

ⓑ w. a group or company fr. which separation or dissociation takes place (Hyperid. 6, 17 and Lucian, Cyn. 13 ἐξ ἀνθρώπων) ἐξολεθρεύειν ἐκ τοῦ λαοῦ Ac 3:23 (Ex 30:33; Lev 23:29). συμβιβάζειν ἐκ τ. ὄχλου 19:33; ἐκλέγειν ἐκ τ. κόσμου J 15:19; cp. Mt 13:41, 47; Ac 1:24; 15:22; Ro 9:24. For ἐκ freq. ἐκ μέσου Mt 13:49; Ac 17:33; 23:10; 1 Cor 5:2; 2 Cor 6:17 (cp. Ex 31:14).—ἀνιστάναι τινὰ ἔκ τινων Ac 3:22 (Dt 18:15); ἐκ νεκρῶν 17:31. ἐγείρειν τινὰ ἐκ νεκρῶν J 12:1, 9, 17; Ac 3:15; 4:10; 13:30; Hb 11:19; AcPlCor 2:6; ἀνίστασθαι ἐκ νεκρῶν Ac 10:41; 17:3; ἀνάστασις ἐκ νεκρ. Lk 20:35; 1 Pt 1:3; cp. Ro 10:7. Also s. ἠρεμέω.

ⓒ of situations and circumstances out of which someone is brought, from: ἐξαγοράζειν ἔκ τινος redeem fr. someth. Gal 3:13; also λυτροῦν (cp. Sir 51:2) 1 Pt 1:18; σῴζειν ἔκ τινος save fr. someth. J 12:27; Hb 5:7; Js 5:20 (Od. 4, 753; MLetronne, Recueil des Inscr. 1842/8, 190; 198 σωθεὶς ἐκ; SIG 1130, 1f; UPZ 60:6f [s. διασῴζω]; PVat A, 7 [168 b.c.]=Witkowski 36, 7 διασεσῶσθαι ἐκ μεγάλων κινδύνων; Sir 51:11; EpJer 49; JosAs 4:8 ἐκ τοῦ … λιμοῦ); ἐξαιρεῖσθαι Ac 7:10 (cp. Wsd 10:1; Sir 29:12). τηρεῖν ἔκ τινος keep from someth. Rv 3:10; μεταβαίνειν ἔκ τινος εἴς τι J 5:24; 1J 3:14; μετανοεῖν ἔκ τινος repent and turn away fr. someth. Rv 2:21f; 9:20f; 16:11. ἀναπαύεσθαι ἐκ τ. κόπων rest fr. one’s labors 14:13. ἐγείρεσθαι ἐξ ὕπνου wake fr. sleep (Epict. 2, 20, 15; Sir 22:9; cp. ParJer 5:2 οὐκ ἐξυπνίσθη ἐκ τοῦ ὕπνου αὐτοῦ) Ro 13:11. ζωὴ ἐκ νεκρῶν 11:15. ζῶντες ἐκ νεκρῶν people who have risen fr. death to life 6:13 (cp. Soph., Oed. R. 454; X., An. 7, 7, 28; Demosth. 18, 131 ἐλεύθερος ἐκ δούλου καὶ πλούσιος ἐκ πτωχοῦ γεγονώς; Palaeph. 3, 2). S. ἀνάστασις 2b.

ⓓ of pers. and things with whom a connection is severed or is to remain severed: τηρεῖν αὐτοὺς ἐκ τοῦ πονηροῦ keep them fr. the evil one J 17:15; cp. Ac 15:29. Pregnant constr.: ἀνανήφειν ἐκ τῆς τοῦ διαβόλου παγίδος 2 Ti 2:26. νικᾶν ἔκ τινος free oneself from … by victory Rv 15:2 (for possible Latinism s. reff. to Livy and Velleius Paterculus in OLD s.v. ‘victoria’; but s. also RCharles, ICC Rv II, 33). ἐλεύθερος ἐκ 1 Cor 9:19 (cp. Eur., Herc. Fur. 1010 ἐλευθεροῦντες ἐκ δρασμῶν πόδα ‘freeing our feet from flight’ [=we recovered from our flight]). καθαρός εἰμι ἐγὼ ἐξ αὐτῆς I practiced abstinence with her GJs 15:4.

② marker denoting the direction fr. which someth. comes, from καταβαίνειν ἐκ τοῦ ὄρους (Il. 13, 17; X., An. 7, 4, 12; Ex 19:14; 32:1 al.; JosAs 4:1 ἐκ τοῦ ὑπερῴου) Mt 17:9. θρὶξ ἐκ τῆς κεφαλῆς ὑμῶν οὐ μὴ ἀπόληται Lk 21:18. ἐκπίπτειν ἐκ τ. χειρῶν Ac 12:7. διδάσκειν ἐκ τοῦ πλοίου Lk 5:3. ἐκ τῆς βάτου χρηματισμοῦ διδομένου 1 Cl 17:5 (cp. Just., A I, 62:3). ἐκ τῆς πρύμνης ῥίψαντες τὰς ἀγκύρας Ac 27:29. κρέμασθαι ἔκ τινος (Hom. et al.; 1 Macc 1:61; 2 Macc 6:10; Jos., Ant. 14, 107) 28:4. ἐκ ῥιζῶν to (lit. from) its roots (Job 28:9; 31:12) Mk 11:20; B 12:9.—Since the Greek feeling concerning the relation betw. things in this case differed fr. ours, ἐκ could answer the question ‘where?’ (cp. Soph., Phil. 20; Synes., Ep. 131 p. 267a ἐκ τῆς ἑτέρας μερίδος=on the other side; BGU 975, 11; 15 [45 a.d.]; PGM 36, 239; LXX; JosAs 16:12 εἱστήκει … ἐξ εὐωνύμων; 22:7) ἐκ δεξιῶν at (on) the right (δεξιός 1b) Mt 20:21, 23; 22:44 (Ps 109:1); 25:33; Lk 1:11; Ac 2:25 (Ps 15:8), 34 (Ps 109:1); 7:55f; B 11:10. ἐξ ἐναντίας opposite Mk 15:39 (Hdt. 8, 6, 2; Thu. 4, 33, 1; Mitt-Wilck. I/2, 461, 6; Sir 37:9; Wsd 4:20 al.); ὁ ἐξ ἐναντίας the opponent (Sext. Emp., Adv. Phys. 1, 66 [=Adv. Math. 9, 66]; 2, 69 [=Adv. Math. 10, 69], Adv. Eth. 1, 25; Bias in Diog. L. 1, 84) Tit 2:8.—ἐκ τοῦ κατωτάτου ᾅδου … προσευχομένου Ἰωνᾶ AcPlCor 2:30.

③ marker denoting origin, cause, motive, reason, from, of

ⓐ in expr. which have to do w. begetting and birth from, of, by: ἐκ introduces the role of the male (Ps.-Callisth. 1, 9 ἐκ θεοῦ ἔστι; JosAs 21:8 συνέλαβεν Ἀσενὲθ ἐκ τοῦ Ἰωσήφ; Tat. 33, 3 συλλαμβάνουσιν ἐκ φθορέως; Ath. 22, 4 ἐκ τοῦ Κρόνου; SIG 1163, 3; 1169, 63; OGI 383, 3; 5 [I b.c.]) ἐν γαστρὶ ἔχειν ἔκ τινος Mt 1:18. κοίτην ἔχειν ἔκ τινος Ro 9:10; also of the female (SIG 1160, 3; PEleph 1, 9 [311/10 b.c.] τεκνοποιεῖσθαι ἐξ ἄλλης γυναικός; PFay 28, 9 γεννᾶσθαι ἐκ; Demetr.: 722 Fgm. 1, 14 Jac.; Jos., Ant. 1, 191; Ath. 20, 3 ἐξ ἧς παῖς Διόνυσος αὐτῷ) γεννᾶν τινα ἐκ beget someone by (a woman; s. γεννάω 1a) Mt 1:3, 5, etc. ἐκ Μαρίας ἐγεννῄθη AcPlCor 1:14; 2:5; γίνεσθαι ἐκ γυναικός (Jos., Ant. 11, 152; Ar. 9, 7) Gal 4:4; cp. vs. 22f.—γεννᾶσθαι ἐξ αἱμάτων κτλ. J 1:13; ἐκ τ. σαρκός 3:6; ἐκ πορνείας 8:41. ἐγείρειν τινὶ τέκνα ἐκ Mt 3:9; Lk 3:8. (τὶς) ἐκ καρποῦ τ. ὀσφύος αὐτοῦ Ac 2:30 (Ps 131:11). γεννᾶσθαι ἐκ τ. θεοῦ J 1:13; 1J 3:9; 4:7; 5:1, 4, 18 (Just., A I, 22, 2); ἐκ τ. πνεύματος J 3:6 (opp. ἐκ τ. σαρκός). εἶναι ἐκ τοῦ θεοῦ (Menand., Sam. 602 S. [257 Kö.]) J 8:47; 1J 4:4, 6; 5:19; opp. εἶναι ἐκ τ. διαβόλου J 8:44; 1J 3:8 (cp. OGI 90, 10 of Ptolemaeus Epiphanes ὑπάρχων θεὸς ἐκ θεοῦ κ. θεᾶς).

ⓑ to denote origin as to family, race, city, people, district, etc.: ἐκ Ναζαρέτ J 1:46. ἐκ πόλεως vs. 44. ἐξ οἴκου Lk 1:27; 2:4. ἐκ γένους (Jos., Ant. 11, 136) Phil 3:5; Ac 4:6. ἐκ φυλῆς (Jos., Ant. 6, 45; 49; PTebt I, 26, 15) Lk 2:36; Ac 13:21; 15:23; Ro 11:1. Ἑβρ. ἐξ Ἑβραίων a Hebrew, the son of Hebrews Phil 3:5 (Goodsp., Probs., 175f; on the connotation of ancestral ἀρετή Phil 3:5 cp. New Docs VII 233, no. 10, 5). ἐκ σπέρματός τινος J 7:42; Ro 1:3; 11:1. ἐξ ἐθνῶν Ac 15:23; cp. Gal 2:15. Cp. Lk 23:7; Ac 23:34. ἐκ τ. γῆς J 3:31. For this ἐκ τῶν κάτω J 8:23 (opp. ἐκ τ. ἄνω). ἐκ (τούτου) τ. κόσμου 15:19ab; 17:14; 1J 2:16; 4:5. ἐξ οὐρανοῦ ἢ ἐξ ἀνθρώπων Mt 21:25; Mk 11:30.—To express a part of the whole, subst.: οἱ ἐξ Ἰσραήλ the Israelites Ro 9:6. οἱ ἐξ ἐριθείας selfish, factious people 2:8. οἱ ἐκ νόμου partisans of the law 4:14; cp. vs. 16. οἱ ἐκ πίστεως those who have faith Gal 3:7, 9; cp. the sg. Ro 3:26; 4:16. οἱ ἐκ περιτομῆς the circumcision party Ac 11:2; Ro 4:12; Gal 2:12. οἱ ἐκ τῆς περιτομῆς Tit 1:10. For this οἱ ὄντες ἐκ περιτομῆς Col 4:11. οἱ ἐκ τ. συναγωγῆς members of the synagogue Ac 6:9. οἱ ἐκ τῶν Ἀριστοβούλου Ro 16:10f. οἱ ἐκ τῆς Καίσαρος οἰκίας Phil 4:22 (s. Καῖσαρ and οἰκία 3). In these cases the idea of belonging, the partisan use, often completely overshadows that of origin; cp. Dg 6:3.

ⓒ to denote derivation (Maximus Tyr. 13, 3f φῶς ἐκ πυρός; Ath. 18:3 γένεσιν … ἐξ ὕδατος) καπνὸς ἐκ τ. δόξης τ. θεοῦ Rv 15:8 (cp. EpJer 20 καπνὸς ἐκ τ. οἰκίας). ἡ σωτηρία ἐκ τ. Ἰουδαίων ἐστίν J 4:22. εἶναι ἔκ τινος come, derive from someone or someth. (Jos., Ant. 7, 209) Mt 5:37; J 7:17, 22; 1J 2:16, 21; εἶναι is oft. to be supplied Ro 2:29; 11:36; 1 Cor 8:6 ( Plut., Mor. 1001c); 11:12; 2 Cor 4:7; Gal 5:8. ἔργα ἐκ τοῦ πατρός J 10:32. οἰκοδομὴ ἐκ θεοῦ 2 Cor 5:1; χάρισμα 1 Cor 7:7; δικαιοσύνη Phil 3:9. φωνὴ ἐκ τ. στόματος αὐτοῦ Ac 22:14. Here belongs the constr. w. ἐκ for the subj. gen., as in ἡ ἐξ ὑμῶν (v.l.) ἀγάπη 2 Cor 8:7; ὁ ἐξ ὑμῶν ζῆλος 9:2 v.l.; Rv 2:9 (cp. Vett. Val. 51, 16; CIG II 3459, 11 τῇ ἐξ ἑαυτῆς κοσμιότητι; pap. [Rossberg 14f]; 1 Macc 11:33 χάριν τῆς ἐξ αὐτῶν εὐνοίας; 2 Macc 6:26). ἐγένετο ζήτησις ἐκ τ. μαθητῶν Ἰωάννου there arose a discussion on the part of John’s disciples J 3:25 (Dionys. Hal. 8, 89, 4 ζήτησις πολλὴ ἐκ πάντων ἐγένετο; Appian, Bell. Civ. 2, 24 §91 σφαγή τις ἐκ τῶν στρατιωτῶν ἐγένετο).

ⓓ of the effective cause by, because of (cp. the ‘perfectivizing’ force of ἐκ and other prepositions in compounds, e.g. Mt 4:7; Mk 9:15. B-D-F §318, 5)

α. personal in nature, referring to originator (X., An. 1, 1, 6; Diod S 19, 1, 4 [saying of Solon]; Arrian, Anab. 3, 1, 2; 4, 13, 6 of an inspired woman κατεχομένη ἐκ τοῦ θείου; Achilles Tat. 5, 27, 2; SibOr 3, 395; Just.: A I, 12, 5 ἐκ δαιμόνων φαύλων … καὶ ταῦτα … ἐνεργεῖσθαι, also D. 18, 3; Nicetas Eugen. 7, 85 H. ἐκ θεῶν σεσωσμένη; Ps.-Clem., Hom. p. 7, 19 Lag. τὸν ἐκ θεοῦ σοι ἀποδιδόμενον μισθόν): ὠφελεῖσθαι ἔκ τινος Mt 15:5; Mk 7:11. ζημιοῦσθαι 2 Cor 7:9. λυπεῖσθαι 2:2. εὐχαριστεῖσθαι 1:11. ἀδικεῖσθαι Rv 2:11. ἐξ ἐμαυτοῦ οὐκ ἐλάλησα J 12:49 (cp. Soph., El. 344 οὐδὲν ἐξ σαυτῆς λέγεις).

β. impersonal in nature (Arrian, Anab. 3, 21, 10 ἀποθνῄσκειν ἐκ τ. τραυμάτων; 6, 25, 4; JosAs 29:8 ἐκ τοῦ τραύματος τοῦ λίθου; POxy 486, 32 τὰ ἐμὰ ἐκ τ. ἀναβάσεως τ. Νίλου ἀπολωλέναι): ἀποθανεῖν ἐκ τ. ὑδάτων Rv 8:11. πυροῦσθαι 3:18. σκοτοῦσθαι 9:2. φωτίζεσθαι 18:1. κεκοπιακὼς ἐκ τῆς ὁδοιπορίας J 4:6 (Aelian, VH 3, 23 ἐκ τοῦ πότου ἐκάθευδεν). ἔκαμον ἐκ τῆς ὁδοῦ GJs 15:1.

ⓔ of the reason which is a presupposition for someth.: by reason of, as a result of, because of (X., An. 2, 5, 5; Appian, Bell. Civ. 1, 42 §185 ἐκ προδοσίας; POxy 486, 28f ἐκ τῆς ἐπιστολῆς; Just., A I, 68, 3 ἐξ ἐπιστολῆς; numerous examples in Mayser II/2 p. 388; Philo, De Jos. 184 ἐκ διαβολῆς; Jos., Vi. 430; JosAs 11 παραλελυμένη … ἐκ τῆς πολλῆς ταπεινώσεως; Ar. 8, 6 ἐκ τούτων … τῶν ἐπιτηδευμάτων τῆς πλάνης; Just., A I, 4, 1 ἐκ τοῦ … ὀνόματος; also inf.: 33, 2 ἵνα … ἐκ τοῦ προειρῆσθαι πιστευθῇ 68, 3 al.): δικαιοῦσθαι ἔκ τινος Ro 4:2; Gal 2:16; 3:24; cp. Ro 3:20, 30 (cp. εἴ τις ἐκ γένους [δίκαι]ος=has the right of citizenship by descent [i.e. has the law on his side]: letter of MAurelius 34, ZPE 8, ’71, 170); οὐκ … ἡ ζωὴ αὐτοῦ ἐστιν ἐκ τῶν ὑπαρχόντων αὐτῷ he does not live because of his possessions Lk 12:15. ἐκ ταύτης τ. ἐργασίας Ac 19:25. ἐξ ἔργων λαβεῖν τὸ πνεῦμα Gal 3:2, 5; cp. Ro 11:6. ἐξ ἀναστάσεως λαβεῖν τ. νεκρούς Hb 11:35. ἐσταυρώθη ἐξ ἀσθενείας 2 Cor 13:4. τὸ ἐξ ὑμῶν as far as it depends on you Ro 12:18.—ἐκ τοῦ πόνου in anguish Rv 16:10; cp. vs. 11; 8:13.—ἐκ τούτου for this reason, therefore (SIG 1168, 47; 1169, 18; 44; 62f; BGU 423, 17=Mitt-Wilck. I/2, 480, 17) J 6:66; 19:12.

ⓕ Sim. ἐκ can introduce the means which one uses for a definite purpose, with, by means of (Polyaenus 3, 9, 62 ἐξ ἱμάντος=by means of a thong) ἐκ τοῦ μαμωνᾶ Lk 16:9 (X., An. 6, 4, 9; PTebt 5, 80 [118 b.c.] ἐκ τ. ἱερῶν προσόδων; ParJer 1:7 [of Jerusalem] ἐκ τῶν χειρῶν σου ἀφανισθήτω; Jos., Vi. 142 ἐκ τ. χρημάτων); cp. 8:3.

ⓖ of the source, fr. which someth. flows or comes:

α. λαλεῖν ἐκ τ. ἰδίων J 8:44. ἐκ τοῦ περισσεύματος τ. καρδίας Mt 12:34. τὰ ἐκ τ. ἱεροῦ the food from the temple 1 Cor 9:13. ἐκ τ. εὐαγγελίου ζῆν get one’s living by proclaiming the gospel vs. 14.

β. information, insight, etc. (X., An. 7, 7, 43 ἐκ τῶν ἔργων κατέμαθες; Just., A I, 28, 1 ἐκ τῶν ἡμετέρων συγγραμμάτων … μαθεῖν 34, 2 al.) κατηχεῖσθαι ἐκ Ro 2:18. ἀκούειν ἐκ J 12:34. γινώσκειν Mt 12:33; Lk 6:44; 1J 3:24; 4:6. ἐποπτεύειν 1 Pt 2:12. δεικνύναι Js 2:18 (cp. ἀποδεικνύναι Just., D. 33, 1).

γ. of the inner life, etc., fr. which someth. proceeds (since Il. 9, 486): ἐκ καρδίας Ro 6:17; 1 Pt 1:22 v.l. (cp. Theocr. 29, 4; M. Ant. 3, 3). ἐκ ψυχῆς Eph 6:6; Col 3:23 (X., An. 7, 7, 43, Oec. 10, 4; Jos., Ant. 17, 177; 1 Macc 8:27). ἐκ καθαρᾶς καρδίας 1 Ti 1:5; 2 Ti 2:22; 1 Pt 1:22. ἐξ ὅλης τ. καρδίας σου καὶ ἐξ ὅλης τ. ψυχῆς σου καὶ ἐξ ὅλης τ. διανοίας σου καὶ ἐξ ὅλης τ. ἰσχύος σου Mk 12:30; cp. Lk 10:27 (Dt 6:5; cp. Wsd 8:21; 4 Macc 7:18; Epict. 2, 23, 42 ἐξ ὅλης ψυχῆς). ἐκ πίστεως Ro 14:23; cp. 2 Cor 2:17. Also of circumstances which accompany an action without necessarily being the source of it: γράφειν ἐκ πολλῆς θλίψεως write out of great affliction 2 Cor 2:4; Phil 1:17.

ⓗ of the material out of which someth. is made (Hdt. 1, 194; Pla., Rep. 10, 616c; OGI 194, 28 [42 b.c.] a statue ἐκ σκληροῦ λίθου; PMagd 42, 5 [221 b.c.]=PEnteux 83, 5; POxy 707, 28; PGM 13, 659; Wsd 15:8; 1 Macc 10:11; Jdth 1:2; En 99:13; JosAs 3:9; Just., A I, 59, 1) of, from στέφανος ἐξ ἀκανθῶν Mt 27:29; J 19:2; cp. 2:15; 9:6; Ro 9:21; 1 Cor 15:47; Rv 18:12; 21:21; perh. also 1 Cor 11:12 ἡ γυνὴ ἐκ τοῦ ἀνδρός.

ⓘ of the underlying rule or principle according to, in accordance with (Hdt., Pla. et al. [Kühner-G. I 461g], also OGI 48, 12 [III b.c.] ἐκ τ. νόμων; PEleph 1, 12 [312/11 b.c.] ἐκ δίκης; PPetr III, 26, 9 ἐκ κρίσεως; LXX, e.g. 1 Macc 8:30; Jos., Ant. 6, 296 ἐκ κυνικῆς ἀσκήσεως πεποιημένος τὸν βίον) ἐκ τ. λόγων Mt 12:37 (cp. Wsd 2:20). ἐκ τ. στόματός σου κρινῶ σε by what you have said Lk 19:22 (cp. Sus 61 Theod.; also X., Cyr. 2, 2, 21 ἐκ τ. ἔργων κρίνεσθαι). ἐκ τῶν γεγραμμένων on the basis of things written Rv 20:12. ἐκ τ. καλοῦντος Ro 9:12. ἐκ τ. ἔχειν in accordance w. your ability 2 Cor 8:11. ἐξ ἰσότητος on the basis of equality vs. 13.

④ marker used in periphrasis, from, of

ⓐ for the partitive gen. (B-D-F §164, 1 and 2; 169; Rob. 599; 1379).

α. after words denoting number εἷς, μία, ἕν (Hdt. 2, 46, 2 ἐκ τούτων εἷς; POxy 117, 14ff [II/III a.d.] δύο … ἐξ ὧν … ἓν ἐξ αὐτῶν; Tob 12:15 BA; Sir 32:1; Jos., Bell. 7, 47; JosAs 20:2 ἐκ τῶν παρθένων μία Just., D. 126, 4) Mt 10:29; 18:12; 22:35; 27:48; Mk 9:17 al.; εἷς τις J 11:49; δύο Mk 16:12; Lk 24:13; J 1:35; 21:2. πέντε Mt 25:2. πολλοί (1 Macc 5:26; 9:69) J 6:60, 66; 7:31; 11:19, 45. οἱ πλείονες 1 Cor 15:6. οὐδείς (Epict. 1, 29, 37; 1 Macc 5:54; 4 Macc 14:4; Ar. 13, 6; Just., D. 16, 2) J 7:19; 16:5. χιλιάδες ἐκ πάσης φυλῆς Rv 7:4.

β. after the indef. pron. (Plut., Galba 1065 [27, 2]; Herodian 5, 3, 9; 3 Macc 2:30; Jos., Vi. 279) Lk 11:15; J 6:64; 7:25, 44, 48; 9:16; 11:37, 46 al. Also after the interrog. pron. Mt 6:27; 21:31; Lk 11:5; 12:25; 14:28 al.

γ. the partitive w. ἐκ as subj. (2 Km 11:17) εἶπαν ἐκ τ. μαθητῶν αὐτοῦ J 16:17.—Rv 11:9. As obj., pl. Mt 23:34; Lk 11:49; 21:16; 2J 4 (cp. Sir 33:12; Jdth 7:18; 10:17 al.).

δ. used w. εἶναι belong to someone or someth. (Jos., Ant. 12, 399) καὶ σὺ ἐξ αὐτῶν εἶ you also belong to them Mt 26:73; cp. Mk 14:69f; Lk 22:58; J 7:50; 10:26; Ac 21:8; cp. 2 Cl 18:1. οὐκ εἰμὶ ἐκ τ. σώματος I do not belong to the body 1 Cor 12:15f; cp. 2 Cl 14:1.

ε. after verbs of supplying, receiving, consuming: ἐσθίειν ἔκ τινος (Tob 1:10; Sir 11:19; Jdth 12:2; JosAs 16:8) 1 Cor 9:7; 11:28; J 6:26, 50f; Rv 2:7. πίνειν Mt 26:29; Mk 14:25; J 4:13f; Rv 14:10; χορτάζειν ἔκ τινος gorge w. someth. 19:21 (s. ζ below); μετέχειν 1 Cor 10:17; λαμβάνειν (1 Esdr 6:31; Wsd 15:8) J 1:16; Rv 18:4; Hs 9, 24, 4. τὸ βρέφος … ἔλαβε μασθὸν ἐκ τῆς μητρὸς αὐτοῦ the child took its mother’s breast GJs 19:2; διδόναι (Tob 4:16; Ezk 16:17) Mt 25:8; 1J 4:13. διαδιδόναι (Tob 4:16 A) J 6:11.

ζ. after verbs of filling: ἐπληρώθη ἐκ τῆς ὀσμῆς was filled w. the fragrance J 12:3 cp. Rv 8:5. χορτασθῆναι ἔκ τινος to be satisfied to the full w. someth. Lk 15:16. γέμειν ἐξ ἁρπαγῆς be full of greed Mt 23:25.

ⓑ in periphrasis for the gen. of price or value for (Palaeph. 45; PFay 111, 16 [95/96 a.d.]; 119, 5 [c. 100 a.d.]; 131, 5; PLond II, 277, 9 p. 217 [23 a.d.]; BGU III, 916, 19 [I a.d.]; PAmh II, 133, 19 [II a.d.]; Jos., Ant. 14, 34; B-D-F §179) ἀγοράζειν τι ἔκ τινος Mt 27:7 (POxy 745, 2 [c. 1 a.d.] τ. οἶνον ἠγόρασας ἐκ δραχμῶν ἕξ; EpJer 24); cp. Ac 1:18; Mt 20:2.

⑤ marker denoting temporal sequence, from

ⓐ of the time when someth. begins from, from … on, for, etc. ἐκ κοιλίας μητρός from birth (Ps 21:11; 70:6; Is 49:1) Mt 19:12 al.; also ἐκ γενετῆς J 9:1 (since Il. 24, 535; Od. 18, 6; s. also γενετή). ἐκ νεότητος (since Il. 14, 86; Ps 70:5; Sir 7:23; Wsd 8:2; 1 Macc 2:66; JosAs 17:4) Mk 10:20; Lk 18:21. ἐξ ἱκανῶν χρόνων for a long time 23:8. ἐκ πολλῶν χρόνων a long time before 1 Cl 42:5 (cp. Epict. 2, 16, 17 ἐκ πολλοῦ χρόνου. Cp. ἐκ πολλοῦ Thu. 1, 68, 3; 2, 88, 2; ἐξ ὀλίγων ἡμερῶν Lysias, Epitaph. 1). ἐκ γενεῶν ἀρχαίων Ac 15:21 (cp. X., Hell. 6, 1, 4 ἐκ πάντων προγόνων). ἐκ τ. αἰῶνος since the world began J 9:32 (cp. ἐξ αἰῶνος Sext. Emp., Adv. Math. 9, 76; Diod S 4, 83, 3; Aelian, VH 6, 13; 12, 64; OGI 669, 61; Sir 1:4; 1 Esdr 2:17, 21; Jos., Bell. 5, 442). ἐξ ἐτῶν ὀκτώ for eight years Ac 9:33; cp. 24:10. ἐξ ἀρχῆς (PTebt 40, 20 [117 b.c.]; Sir 15:14; 39:32; Jos., C. Ap. 1, 225; Ath. 8, 1) J 6:64. ἐκ παιδιόθεν fr. childhood Mk 9:21 (s. παιδιόθεν. Just., A I, 15, 6 ἐκ παίδων. On the use of ἐκ w. an adv. cp. ἐκ τότε POxy 486 [II a.d.]; ἐκ πρωίθεν 1 Macc 10:80).

ⓑ of temporal sequence

α. ἡμέραν ἐξ ἡμέρας day after day 2 Pt 2:8; 2 Cl 11:2 (cp. Ps.-Eur., Rhes. 445; Henioch. Com. 5:13 K.; Theocr. 18, 35; Gen 39:10; Num 30:15; Sir 5:7; Esth 3:7; En 98:8; 103:10).

β. ἐκ δευτέρου for the second time, again, s. δεύτερος 2. ἐκ τρίτου Mt 26:44 (ParJer 7:8; cp. PHolm 1, 32 ἐκ τετάρτου).

⑥ various uses and units

ⓐ blending of constructions, cp. Rob. 599f: ἐκ for ἐν (Hdt., Thu. et al., s. Kühner-G. I 546f; LXX, e.g. Sus 26 Theod.; 1 Macc 11:41; 13:21; Jdth 15:5) ὁ πατὴρ ὁ ἐξ οὐρανοῦ δώσει Lk 11:13. μὴ καταβάτω ἆραι τὰ ἐκ τῆς οἰκίας αὐτοῦ Mt 24:17. τὴν ἐκ Λαοδικείας (ἐπιστολὴν) ἵνα καὶ ὑμεῖς ἀναγνῶτε Col 4:16.

ⓑ like the OT use of מִן: ἔκρινεν ὁ θεὸς τὸ κρίμα ὑμῶν ἐξ αὐτῆς God has pronounced judgment for you against her Rv 18:20 (cp. Ps 118:84; Is 1:24; En 100:4; 104:3). ἐξεδίκησεν τὸ αἷμα τ. δούλων αὐτοῦ ἐκ χειρὸς αὐτῆς 19:2, cp. 6:10 (both 4 Km 9:7).

ⓒ adv. expressions (Just., A I, 2, 1 ἐκ παντὸς τρόπου ‘in every way’): ἐξ ἀνάγκης (ἀνάγκη 1). ἐκ συμφώνου by mutual consent (BGU 446, 13=Mitt-Wilck. II/2, 257, 13; CPR I, 11, 14 al. in pap; cp. Dssm., NB 82f [BS 225]) 1 Cor 7:5. ἐκ λύπης reluctantly 2 Cor 9:7. ἐκ περισσοῦ extremely (Dio Chrys. 14 [31], 64; Lucian, Pro Merc. Cond. 13; Da 3:22 Theod.; Galen, CMG V/10/2/2 p. 284, 17 [-ττ]) Mk 6:51; 1 Th 5:13 v.l.; ἐκ μέτρου by measure = sparingly J 3:34. ἐκ μέρους (Galen, CMG V/10/2/2 p. 83, 24) part by part = as far as the parts are concerned, individually 1 Cor 12:27 (distributive; cp. PHolm 1, 7 ἐκ δραχμῶν Ϛ´=6 dr. each); mostly in contrast to ‘complete’, only in part 13:9 (BGU 538, 35; 574, 10; 887, 6; 17 al. in pap; EpArist 102). ἐξ ὀνόματος individually, personally, by name IEph 20:2; IPol 4:2; 8:2.

ⓓ ἐκ … εἰς w. the same word repeated gives it special emphasis (Plut., Galba 1058 [14, 2] ἐκ προδοσίας εἰς προδοσίαν; Ps 83:8) ἐκ πίστεως εἰς πίστιν Ro 1:17.—2 Cor 2:16 (twice).—The result and goal are thus indicated Ro 11:36; 1 Cor 8:6; Col 1:16. AFridrichsen, ConNeot 12, ’48, 54.—DELG s.v. ἐξ. M-M.
```

I've highlighted the areas that pertain to our cup. The info is in the first section marked ⓐ. Look for the words "After πίνειν, of the object fr. which one drinks"

So as you can see, language is not a collection of universal codes. Instead the same word can have a host of usages, sometimes the same word being its own opposite. So what linguists do is they collect all the expressions people use even when they seem to be breaking the rules and explain what the context clearly indicates that they mean. Here are some ways we use the word "out of" that have nothing to do with "out of" or "away from":

- We're out of coffee
- You're out of line
- I was going out of my mind

Etc. We use words in peculiar ways.

This is an online lexicon that you may find useful:  http://logeion.uchicago.edu/%E1%BC%90%CE%BA